# ubuntu apt-get upgrade - how to click Ok in shell?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I was upgrading the openssh-server package using `apt-get upgrade` on my Ubuntu 7.04 server, in order to fix the debian PRNG security bug. I was doing so over an SSH connection (putty on windows) which I thought was ok but...

The upgrade seems to have hung at the following, it's like it wants me to click "Ok" in the "window" but of course I can't because I'm just in a shell.

Setting up openssh-server (4.3p2-8ubuntu1.5) ...
   Package configuration

```
ââââââââââââââââââââââââ¤ Configuring openssh-server âââââââââââââââââââââââââ
â                                                                           â
â Vulnerable host keys will be regenerated                                  â
â                                                                           â®
â Some of the OpenSSH server host keys on this system were generated with   â
â a version of OpenSSL that had a broken random number generator. As a      â
â result, these host keys are from a well-known set, are subject to         â
â brute-force attacks, and must be regenerated.                             â
â                                                                           â
â Users of this system should be informed of this change, as they will be   â
â prompted about the host key change the next time they log in. Use         â
â 'ssh-keygen -l -f HOST_KEY_FILE' after the upgrade has changed to print   â
â the fingerprints of the new host keys.                                    â
â                                                                           â
â The affected host keys are:                                               â
â                                                                           â
â
â                                  <Ok>
â                                                                           â
âââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââ
```

I notice that I can't connect any new ssh sessions to the server anymore, but an existing one I have open still works.

Any ideas how I can proceed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ensure the Putty window has focus, then try hitting "Enter".  If that doesn't work, hit "Tab" until the "< Ok >" is highlighted and then try "Enter" again.

Comment: Sweet, thanks! I had tried hitting "Enter" many times, and practically every other key, but never considered "Tab". Tab to select, then Enter, worked like a charm!!